# Network Profiler has moved

Tags: android, android-studio, profiling

I've updated android studio from `arctic fox` to latest version `bumblebee 2021.1.1` on Macbook. I'm using profiler and unable to do network profiling as it shows `Network Profiler has moved` and beneath that it shows `To inspect network activity. Use the Network Inspector`. And when I click on that highlighted `Network Inspector` it moves me to `App Inspection` section where nothing shows.

[image]

And this is what I get when click on `Network Inspector`

[image]

Comment: Any chance you have an authoritative answer to the 2 questions regarding [Network inspector data unavailable in Android Studio 2022.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76101557/3154666)? Thank you

Answer (score 13):

> Network Inspection: The Network Profiler has now migrated to the App Inspection tool window, to allow for a lighter-weight experience for inspecting network traffic in your app. The look and feel of the Network Profiler has been maintained and works with any debuggable app on devices running API level 26 and higher. To use the new inspector, select **View > Tool Windows > App Inspection** from the menu bar and select the Network Inspector. For more information, see Inspect network traffic with the Network Inspector.

Refer https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/01/android-studio-bumblebee-202111-stable.html

Comment: android Studio - Bumblebee energy profiler unable to select range, do u have any idea on this ?

Comment: Have you any idea about how can we remove it from App inspection? I cannot use Database inspection because of stupid issues of Network inspector

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are some bugs in latest Android Studio version "Bumblebee 2021.1.1".

*Hack/Workaround:*
**Start the application from the android studio itself and not from your phone.**
Then it will show the network details you need to see. If it does not show the network details automatically choose the application process by selecting the device from the app inspection window.

- *The above fix is working fine in Windows also.*

There are some other issues also in network profiler in latest version:

- You might not be able to stop the network profiler completely. Even
  after clicking on "Stop inspectors" it still continues to show
  network details.
- Reduced internet speed.
- Issues in playing online videos (tested in exoPlayer).

Comment: Android Studio - Bumblebee energy profiler unable to select range, do u have any idea on this ?